# How to speed up the execution of MySQL queries where multiple tables are involved

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have 13 tables with about 5-6 columns each. Out of 13 tables, 4 tables have more than 200,000 (0.2 million) rows with 5-6 columns having varchar(1000) or more value. Rest 10 tables are having around 10000 rows with 5-6 columns each with varchar(1000) or more value. Whenever I am writing query which includes data from >=3 tables, with expected result of 1000 rows and 5 columns, the query execution is taking lot of time, around (30 minutes-2 hours).

I have system of approx 12GB RAM and x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

What are the possible ways to reduce the query execution time drastically?

```
select a.d_id, 
       a.d_n, 
       a.t_id, a.act, 
       a.pm, 
       b.d_t, 
       b.d_d, 
       b.pm, 
       b.mec_of_act, 
       b.d_g, 
       b.d_c, 
       c.n_id, 
       c.s_name, 
       c.s_status, 
       c.s_p, 
       c.dis 
from    d_tar a, 
       d_char b, 
       ct c, 
       c_int d, 
       d_s e,
       d_b f 
where   a.d_id=b.d_id 
&&      a.d_id=e.d_id 
&&      t_id='847' 
&&      a.d_id=f.d_id 
&&      d.n_id=c.n_id 
&&      (d.in_name=b.d_n 
          or d.in_name=e.snym 
          or d.in_name=f.b_name);
```

Comment: Show us the query, explain plan..

Comment: Your query needs optimizations. I'm working on 3 times worse server and fetching data from 4 tables from which one got 10+M records and rest about 0.5+M each. I takes about ~1-2s when server is busy.

Comment: I suggest you learn to use explicit joins - `FROM d_tar a JOIN d_char b ON a.d_id = b.d_id JOIN ...`. It makes it so much easier to see what's going on.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely basic, so I'm sure you have already done it. But just in case, be sure to set query logging in your my.ini file and see if maybe your indexes are not always set correctly.

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1  
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = "E:/wamp/logs/slowquery.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields you are joining on indexed and similar data types?

Also, looking at your query you appear to being doing joins based on OR between a couple of tables, which I suspect will might prevent MySQL usefully using indexes.

Try this with explicit joins, which makes the joins more obvious, and post the EXPLAIN for it:-

```
SELECT a.d_id, 
       a.d_n, 
       a.t_id, 
       a.act, 
       a.pm, 
       b.d_t, 
       b.d_d, 
       b.pm, 
       b.mec_of_act, 
       b.d_g, 
       b.d_c, 
       c.n_id, 
       c.s_name, 
       c.s_status, 
       c.s_p, 
       c.dis 
FROM d_tar a
INNER JOIN d_char b ON a.d_id=b.d_id 
INNER JOIN d_b f ON a.d_id=f.d_id 
INNER JOIN d_s e ON a.d_id=e.d_id 
INNER JOIN c_int d ON d.in_name IN (b.d_n, e.snym, f.b_name)
INNER JOIN ct c ON d.n_id=c.n_id 
WHERE   a.t_id='847'
```

EDIT - if the join on different column names is preventing useful indexes being used then maybe the following would work (although this assumes c_int.n_id is unique):-

```
SELECT a.d_id, 
       a.d_n, 
       a.t_id, 
       a.act, 
       a.pm, 
       b.d_t, 
       b.d_d, 
       b.pm, 
       b.mec_of_act, 
       b.d_g, 
       b.d_c, 
       CASE WHEN c1.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c1.n_id WHEN c2.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c2.n_id WHEN c3.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c3.n_id END AS n_id,
       CASE WHEN c1.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c1.s_name WHEN c2.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c2.s_name WHEN c3.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c3.s_name END AS s_name,
       CASE WHEN c1.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c1.s_status WHEN c2.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c2.s_status WHEN c3.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c3.s_status END AS s_status,
       CASE WHEN c1.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c1.s_p WHEN c2.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c2.s_p WHEN c3.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c3.s_p END AS s_p,
       CASE WHEN c1.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c1.dis WHEN c2.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c2.dis WHEN c3.n_id IS NOT NULL THEN c3.dis END AS dis
FROM d_tar a
INNER JOIN d_char b ON a.d_id = b.d_id 
INNER JOIN d_b f ON a.d_id = f.d_id 
INNER JOIN d_s e ON a.d_id = e.d_id 
LEFT JOIN c_int d1 ON d1.in_name = b.d_n
LEFT JOIN c_int d2 ON d2.in_name = e.snym
LEFT JOIN c_int d3 ON d3.in_name = f.b_name
LEFT JOIN ct c1 ON d1.n_id = c1.n_id 
LEFT JOIN ct c2 ON d1.n_id = c2.n_id 
LEFT JOIN ct c3 ON d1.n_id = c3.n_id 
WHERE   a.t_id='847' 
AND (c1.n_id IS NOT NULL
OR c2.n_id IS NOT NULL
OR c2.n_id IS NOT NULL)
```